# Calculate the following complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I try to calculate the following integral:

$$\oint_{\{\vert z\vert=3\}}\frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z-2i)}$$

The integral encloses 2 poles in $1$ at $2i$. Using the homotopy we see that expect the two circle of radius $\epsilon$ around both pole, the rest is cancelled out. Now my idea is to try to split the integral into something like
$$\oint_{\{\vert z\vert=3\}}f(z)dz+\oint_{\{\vert z\vert=3\}}f(z)dz$$
and use the cauchy integral formular but I go stucked...

EDIT: If I write now $$
\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2i)}=\frac{A}{z-1}+\frac{B}{z-2i}\ .
$$
as in the answer and I solve it. Then we get$A=-B$ and $A=-\frac{1}{2i-1}$. Okay now we get
$$A\oint_{\{\vert z\vert=3\}}\frac{e^z}{z-1}-A\oint_{\{\vert z\vert=3\}}\frac{e^z}{z-2i}$$
By the Cauchy Formular this is equal to:
$$2\pi iA(e^1+e^{-2i})$$
Is this right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Cauchy integral formula by writing
$$
\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2i)}=\frac{A}{z-1}+\frac{B}{z-2i}\ .
$$

Alternatively, you can use the residue theorem. The answer should be
$$
2\pi i (\textrm{Res}(f;1)+\textrm{Res}(f;2i))
$$
where
$$
\textrm{Res}(f;1)=\frac{e}{1-2i},\quad
\textrm{Res}(f;2i)=\frac{e^{2i}}{2i-1}
$$

Comment: @FrederickManfred: well, $A$ and $B$ are nothing but two complex constants. What is the difficulty?

Comment: See please edit

Comment: @FrederickManfred: I will go on to see you edit:-)

Comment: @FrederickManfred:  I believe my calculation confirms your solution.

Comment: One last question, how could you calculate the residue so "fast"?

Comment: @FrederickManfred: calculating residues for simple poles is easy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Calculating_residues